# openshift, Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0) and neo4j

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, neo4j, openshift

I run a Java EE application on openshift with a Tomcat 7 server, and using neo4j in embedded mode for the persistance layer. I am using the openshift free plan for now. Every now and then, the application stops, and i get a 503 error. I suspect they pause the gear if the application is inactive for some time, but the application never restarts properly.

I have logged in using ssh and inspected the logs in Tomcat, but found no errors. I suspect that neo4j does not get to call shutdown, but i guess it should still recover.

Any ideas? What should i inspect?

Comment: Can you check the neo4j log in `DATA_DIR/graph.db/messages.log`

Comment: Found this, i think these might be some starting points: "You are using an unsupported Java runtime. Please use Oracle Java Runtime Environment 7.". Also, the notorious "Non-clean shutdown detected" -- is this solved by now?

Comment: This happens when your database is hard-killed and not shutdown correctly. Did you add a shutdown hook as explained in the docs?

Answer (score 2):

It the application isn't receiving any external requests for 48 hours it will then get idled. However the application will automatically be restarted once an external request is made. Also since you're using java and your database on small gear, check to make sure you aren't hitting any memory limits (https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1082-how-to-check-for-memory-limit-violations).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. It seems that i have 0 memory limit violations.